# Найти значения из графовой базы данных

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Я пытаюсь найти суммарный объём оперативной памяти (ram) на стойке (rack) ‘DC1-RCK-1-10’ из открытой базы данных Neo4j - https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2 “Network and IT Management”. Для этого я нахожу какие машины связаны с моей стойкой ‘DC1-RCK-1-10’:

```
MATCH (b.Rack) - [:HOLDS] - > (a:Machine) WHERE b.name = ‘DC1-RCK-1-10’ RETURN a
```

Но анализируя связи каждой машины я не вижу ram нода и его так же нет в свойствах. 
Как его найти, чтобы задать связь и найти суммарный для данной стойке?

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли поможет, но всё-таки. Сейчас я стараюсь выполнить аналогичную задачу (которая, возможно, была понята мной вообще неправильно), и мой код

```
MATCH(r:Rack{name:'DC1-RCK-1-10'}) RETURN r
```

Возвращает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно перейти на уровень Type от уровня Machine, там будет свойство ram